# What do the dots next to the fps counter mean?

Tags: overwatch, framerate

When I activate the performance-meter in the settings I can see my FPS in the top left corner.

When the game runs smoothly, I have one dot next to the fps, like that: "FPS: 70." However, in bigger fights I get some input latency (I can feel the delay between moving my mouse and the screen moving, which is very annoying and confusing). The bigger the latency gets the more dots I get next to the FPS, up to 3: "FPS: 70..."

What exactly do these dots mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taken from the forums: http://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20744844281

 (which is quoting something posted on reddit, with no direct link to original post.)

> - one dot means framerate is simulation bound (lots of gameplay to sim, GPU/render is fine)
> - two dots means GPU is saturated
> - three dots means the Render thread (which feeds the GPU) is limiting the framerate

Comment: Thanks, do you think lowering the graphic settings will reduce the 3-dot intervals?

Comment: Not sure, you'd have to test it out on your system.